# How to add Sentence below Click View wording?

Tags: flutter

```
child: Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [


          Text("Click View",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20, color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 201, 102, 100))),

          Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10)),
          Image.asset(
            'Assets/Images/hand_icon.png',
          ),
```

[image: Add sentence below the Click View]

Wanted to add a sentence below the Click View wording

Comment: Row is child of which widget?

Comment: Container widget

Answer (score 0):

```
child: Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
    Column( // Wrap the text and detail sentence in a Column
      children: [
        Text(
          "Click View",
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20, color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 201, 102, 100)),
        ),
        Text(
          "Additional detail sentence", // Add your detail sentence here
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey), // Customize the style as needed
        ),
      ],
    ),
    Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10)),
    Image.asset(
      'Assets/Images/hand_icon.png',
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Row is Horizontal layout widget

```
A -- > B -->)
```

Column is Vertical layout widget.

```
A
|
B
```

You can use row with column and column with row as well: e.g

```
A --> B --> C
      |
      D
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  // Any Widget
                  Text("Click View"), // Add TextStyle
                  // Any Widget
                  Text("Any text"),
                  // Any Widget
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  // Any Widget
                  FlutterLogo(size: 40), // Replace this with Image.asset
                  // Any Widget
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to write a soft description of what will Click view would do. You could use **ListTile** if you want a subtitle below

```
const Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      ListTile(
          title: Text(
            "Click View",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 20,
                color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 201, 102, 100)),
          ),
          subtitle: Text("Sentence below")),
    ],
  ),
```